# Spring Integration: Splitter exception causes subsequent messages to abort

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration, splitter

I have the following configuration, where Im trying to process a list of messages that are split by a splitter. The problem Im facing is that an exception in one of the individual message processing causes all subsequent messages to NOT process. Is there something Im doing wrong?

```
<int:chain input-channel="exceptionTestChannel">
  <int:splitter/>
  <int:header-enricher>
    <int:error-channel ref="myErrorChannel"/>
  </int:header-enricher>
  <int:service-activator id="testExceptionService"
    ref="testExceptionService" method="throwException"></int:service-activator>
  <int:aggregator></int:aggregator>
</int:chain>

<int:channel id="myErrorChannel">
  <int:interceptors>
    <int:wire-tap channel="loggerChannel" />
  </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="exceptionTestChannel">
  <int:interceptors>
    <int:wire-tap channel="loggerChannel" />
  </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>


<int:transformer ref="errorUnwrapper" input-channel="myErrorChannel"  />
```

Exception is below

```
2014-11-12 09:56:30,076 ERROR [com.test.transform.ErrorUnwrapper] - [Payload=org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: com.test.TestServiceException: System Error. Trial test exception][Headers={timestamp=1415814990076, id=a2f50a6d-4de6-3785-e8d8-a5ef9f46c27f}]
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: com.test.TestServiceException: System Error. Trial test exception
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:67)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:167)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:199)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:141)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:273)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:268)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:218)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:883)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: com.test.TestServiceException: System Error. Trial test exception
    at com.test.TestServiceException.getSystemErrorInstance(TestServiceException.java:31)
    at com.test.TestExceptionService.throwException(TestExceptionService.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:122)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:44)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:258)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:103)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:268)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:73)
    ... 50 more
2014-11-12 09:56:30,076 WARN [org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler] - Error message was not delivered.
org.springframework.integration.support.channel.ChannelResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:218)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler.handleError(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.java:83)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:268)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:218)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:883)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

Comment: Please include the exception stack trace in your question. Also, there is a duplicated `<int:chain>` in your XML. Is that intended?

Comment: Sorry about the extra chain..corrected. The exception stack trace is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> an exception in one of the individual message processing causes all subsequent messages to NOT process

You should agree with that it is normal behaviour for any single-thread process: when exception is caused somewhere, all other code won't be invoked.

The simple `split` looks like `for (Object o : collection)`.

To achieve your requirements you need to use `ExecutorChannel` (or `QueueChannel`) as an `output-channel` for `<splitter>`.

Of course, in this case you should pull that `splitter` outside of `<chain>`.

Having that threading shift your messages won't affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

@Artem is correct but another alternative, if you want everything to run on the same thread is to insert a gateway mid-flow.

Just adding an error-channel header like that won't work...

```
<chain>
    <splitter />
    <service-activator ref="gw" />
<chain>

<gateway id="gw" request-channel="foo" error-channel="errors" 
      reply-timeout="0" />

<logging-channel-adapter channel="errors" /> 

<chain input-channel="foo">
    <int:service-activator id="testExceptionService"
        ref="testExceptionService" method="throwException"></int:service-activator>
    <int:aggregator></int:aggregator>
</chain>
```

However, dropping splits like that will cause the default aggregator to never complete the group so you  need a custom release strategy that will release the group even with missing splits.